# UITapGestureRecognizer во время выполнения анимации

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

может ли `UITapGestureRecognizer` отрабатывать во время линейной анимации или при
анимации масштабирования...ежели может, то как запустить = ?

```
self.start = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: centerX + 0.0, y: centerY - 180.0, width: 2, height: 2))//=2
self.start.image = UIImage(named: bu[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(bu.count)))])
self.view.addSubview(self.start)      
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 1.0, options: [ ], animations: { 
  self.start.frame = CGRect(x: centerX - 200.0, y: centerY - 400.0, width: 240, height: 240) },
  completion:nil)        
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 3.0, options: [ ], animations: {     
  self.start.alpha = 0.1
  self.start.frame = CGRect(x: centerX - 200.0, y: centerY - 400.0, width: 240, height: 240) },completion: 
  {animationFinished in self.start.removeFromSuperview()  })  

let tap = start    
let doubleTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer! = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     #selector(ViewController.doubleTapped(_:)))
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
tap!.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true//false =???
self.view!.addSubview(tap!)

tap.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: может ли UITapGestureRecognizer отрабатывать во время линейной анимации или при анимации масштабирования...ежели может, то как запустить = ? @VAndrJ

Comment: Как анимируете? Что именно хотите?

Comment: хотел код положить - не пущают из-за отступа в 4 знака...когда запущена анимация и делаешь Тар во время анимации - не срабатывает...анимация простая - старт от маленького кадра до увеличенного...если закомментировать анимацию, то Тар по статическому имажу работает нормально...нужно чтобы Тар срабатывал во время анимации...

Answer (score 0):

Не понял хода мыслей по коду, поэтому просто приведу пример.

Используйте `UIViewPropertyAnimator` для этих целей.

Запустите пример:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let viewToTap = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    viewToTap.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(viewToTap)

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHolder))
    viewToTap.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, curve: .linear) {
        viewToTap.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 300, width: 200, height: 50)
    }.startAnimation()
}

@objc func tapHolder() {
    print("ok")
}
```

Заменяете все на то что нужно и пользуетесь.

Comment: Какой смысл использовать `@objc` в данном примере?

Comment: Подготовка к переходу на Swift 4, для взаимодействия с Objective-C, чтобы он видел и понимал.

Comment: спасибо, опробовал, буду приклеивать...насчет понятия туговато...@VAndrJ

Comment: @user198638 про  "видел и понимал" я говорил об Objective-Cшном `Selector` :)

Comment: что-то пошло не так...
 UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 2.0,  
 options: [.repeat, .autoreverse],animations: {self.start.frame = CGRect(x:200, y:400, width: 240, height: 240)
  },completion:nil)  // {animationFinished in self.startBubble!.removeFromSuperview()})  (кстати опции висят, но не работают...) - очень нужно .removeFromSuperview...если completion:nil, то ТарGesture все отрабатывает...если заменить на animationFinished in... то анимация идет с завершением, но Tap не срабатывает...что это = ? @VAndrJ

Comment: мое недоразумение = TapGesture не там поместил, сорри за беспокойство...@VAndrJ