# почему не работает UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: { }

Tags: swift

обшаркал инет,но так и не нашел четкого ответа с примером почему не работает в Swift 5.2
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {}...
именно опция .allowUserInteraction...остальные вроде срабатывают...пробовал по разному, но никак...у кого работает - отпишитесь...

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var plate_1_left: UIImageView!
var timer_plate_start: Timer!
var timer_plate_repeat: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
sleep(3)
    
self.timer_plate_start = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: 
self, selector:

#selector(start_plate),userInfo:nil,repeats: false)
    
self.timer_plate_repeat = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target:
self, selector: 

#selector(start_plate),userInfo:nil,repeats: true)
    
   
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: 
"bks0003b.jpg")!)
            
} // func viewDidLoad()


@objc func start_plate(){
    
let placeX_plate = self.view.frame.midX + 300
let placeY_plate = self.view.frame.midY - 400.0
    
print("plate = 0");
    
self.plate_1_left = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: placeX_plate, y:  
placeY_plate, width: 

50, height: 50))
    
self.plate_1_left.image = UIImage(named: "tarelka0001.png")
self.view.addSubview(self.plate_1_left)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 8.0, delay: 0.2, options: 
[.allowUserInteraction], 

animations:
{
self.plate_1_left.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 500, width: 150, height:
100)
}, completion: nil)//{ animationFinished in 
AnimeView.removeFromSuperview()
    
// tap plate

let tap_plate: UIImageView! = self.plate_1_left
    
let tap_plate_1_left: UITapGestureRecognizer! = 
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 

action: #selector(ViewController.tap_plate_1))
    
tap_plate_1_left.delegate = self
tap_plate_1_left.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
//doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2
tap_plate.addGestureRecognizer(tap_plate_1_left) // без этого тап не
tap_plate_1_left.isEnabled = true
self.view!.addSubview(tap_plate)
tap_plate.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // ==???
    
// ***** tapGesture_finish plate_1_left
    
} // func start_plate()
    
@objc func tap_plate_1() {
print("tap_plate_1");
           
} // func tap_plate_1()
    
} // class
```

Comment: Что анимируете и в чем заключается "не работает"?

Comment: летит тарелочка (анимация от 0.0 до 220х475) во время полета "тап" где - то среди трассы... эффекта нет...т е изображение долетает до конечного пункта и тогда тап срабатывает нормально...пробовал var allowUserInteraction: UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: 1) но тоже =нуль...похоже эта опция для UIButton или чего-то подобного...@VAndrJ

Comment: Так а анимируете-то что? frame / constraint / etc, полный код нужен где проблема воспроизводится.

Comment: добавил код здесь работающий проект https://yadi.sk/d/g9hE5FqJ9EyOQg @VAndrJ

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UITapGestureRecognizer во время выполнения анимации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687046/uitapgesturerecognizer-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: и все-таки...почему не срабатывает впрямую=? аппл пишет https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/uiviewanimationoptionallowuserinteraction @VAndrJ